# Input leter with number into if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

How can i make it so that if a user enters, P(any number) that it still enters my if statement below.

```
if ( input =='P')
{
 .....
}
```

Do i have to change something in my if statement?

Basically if they enter the value P with any number following such as P4 or P2, it will go into that if statement.

Comment: What is `input`? (ie, a `char`? a `string`?) How are you giving it its value?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you've defined "input" as a C string, like this:

```
  char input[8];
  fgets (input, 8, stdin);
```

In that case, you can check for "begins with P" like this:

```
if ( input[0] =='P')
{
 .....
}
```

The same syntax would also work if you instead defined "input" as std::string:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
if ( input[0] =='P')
{
 .....
}
```